# WPF Map Control - Manipulation events on MapLayer Children

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, pixelsense

I'm using the WPF Bing Map Control in a Surface application. I have Popup boxes that come up when a user touches a building on the map. I want the popups to be manipulation enabled, so a user can move them, scale and rotate. Right now if you touch and drag within the popup, it moves the map, since it is a child of the map layer. But no matter which sub element of the popup control I add the IsManipulationEnabled and ManipulationStarting etc to, is doesn't fire any manipulation events. So..

Is there a way I can get manipulation events to fire for a child of the map layer?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Try searching for implementations of draggable map pushpins. I know its not the same as what you are looking to do, but I think it should help and it has definitely been done before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call CaptureTouch on your popup element (ie: popup.CaptureTouch()).
This will route all touch gestures to your popup and probably release capture on the map.
I had the same issue with mouse capture and CaptureMouse solved my problems.